# DTCoreText.h file not found in xcode

Tags: objective-c

I am new to objective C and I am trying to use DTCoreText in my project for html content . I followed this link (https://github.com/yas375/DTCoreTextExperiments/tree/master/Pods/DTCoreText) but I am getting the following error: DTCoreText.h file not found . Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I just had the exact same problem, **DTCoreText.h file not found**. I followed the Setup Guide at https://docs.cocoanetics.com/DTCoreText/docs/Setup%20Guide.html, but it still didn't work.

The problem turned out to be that the path i used was not exactly the same as in the guide. I had already included some other external libraries, so i put DTCoreText under `External Libraries/DTCoreText`, and wrote `External Libraries/DTCoreText/Core/**` in the User Header Search Paths-field.

The solution for me was to change this to `"External Libraries/DTCoreText/Core/**"`, note the added quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't download zip file, just clone the project in which you can open the Xcode project then run the demo:

`git clone --recursive https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText.git Externals/DTCoreText`

Comment: recommend to use CocoaPods to handle all the download & update stuff.

Comment: @Raptor thanks,but if I just want to view its demo,not to import it to my app,CocoaPods is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, that while adding DTCoreText you did not select the option "Copy items in destination's folder (if needed). Just select that option while adding files to your project.
And one thing more, always describe what you have dome in detail when ask question. It helps to find the exact solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be copy vs. reference that is your problem. [DTCoreText Setup Guide](https://docs.cocoanetics.com/DTCoreText/docs/Setup%20Guide.html) says "Make sure to uncheck the Copy checkbox. You want to create a reference, not a copy."

You might want to follow that document and start with the DTCoreText demo code in the [original repo](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) just to get started.

Without having your whole project I can't help much with your current problem but you might check the paths you have in "User Header Search Paths" in your project Build Settings tab. I added the DTCoreText project as a reference like the setup doc says, and using `Externals/DTCoreText/Core/**` worked OK. Make sure you have the `**`, meaning the path should be searched recursively.

Comment: I created a new project just for testing purpose and followed the steps specified in https://docs.cocoanetics.com/DTCoreText/docs/Setup%20Guide.html under Project Setup=>Adding the Sub-Project. I added #import "DTCoreText.h" to viewcontroller.m file but I am still getting that error.